# Can other Gmail users access my Google Drive files?

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

I have many files sitting in my Google Drive account.  My account is probably set to whatever the default settings are.  I am the only individual with access to my Gmail password.

Can other individuals (people I consistently email,  people in friends with on Google Plus) get access to these files? Can they download these files or get any access to them (note that my settings are likely set to the default settings) if they are simply sitting in my Google Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only your account has access to those files. You have to explicitly share files for other people to see them.